# Calculate distance to start deceleration to stop at a point

Tags: acceleration

I am trying to program a game where I want an object to accelerate up to a point and the start decelerating so that it comes to a stop at point 0.

Given that I know the Velocity and Position, Acceleration is constant(acceleration and deceleration are the same) and I want to stop at point 0.

How do I work out the distance to start decelerating to stop at point 0.

To think of a Simple example lets say my initial velocity would be 0. acceleration will always be 10 and I start at point -100 and want to stop at point 0.

for the purpose of this I don't need anything like mass or friction.

Comment: Have you looked anything up for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the initial velocity is along the acceleration, then go back to the position from where it would have started to get to the given initial position and velocity. This can be found by subtracting
(1/2)(accn)(time)^2,
Where time=initial velocity/accn
Then the distance to be stopped at would be half the distance between the new position and the destination by symmetry

Comment: That's What I needed, Its always going to be half The distance from the point I started Accelerating

Answer (score 0):

Use the equation $$v^2 = u^2 +2aS$$ where $v$ is the final velocity $=0$ in your case, $u$ is the initial velocity, $a$ is the acceleration and $S$ is the displacement.

Just plug in the values with sign, and you'll arrive at your required answer.